# Determining current owner of SQL Server instance is by interrogating Failover Cluster Management Service using C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, failovercluster

How can I determine who the current owner of SQL Server instance is by interrogating Failover Cluster Management Service using C#?

This is on SQL Server 2008. I have the fail over cluster management service configured and I need a programmatic way to determine the current owner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you need to do that? You can have a look at the API reference and the function called GetClusterGroupState, but needing that somehow seems a bit awkward IMHO.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369611(v=VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369611%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

BR